# Many instances of solarconfig.xml in Solr

Tags: solr

I want to index my database using Solr but I found a link http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart. There are many solrconfig.xml in the unzipped version of Solr 5.2.Can you please tell me the exact location of solrconfig.xml to modify to accomodate these changes.
   Also If possible can you provide me links for indexing database using Solr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to create a collection using solr create -c  and solrconfig.xml would be created by you automatically

Answer (score 0):

Look at [following](http://blog.comperiosearch.com/blog/2014/08/28/indexing-database-using-solr/) for step by step instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Before running DIH you need to create a core. Follow instruction at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr

If you want to create your core by your self

```
1) Create a folder under $SOLR_INSTALL/server/solr/mysolr (name this as per your choice)

2) Create a folder named "conf" under $SOLR_INSTALL/server/solr/mysolr

3) Copy from $SOLR_INSTALL/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf to $SOLR_INSTALL/server/solr/mysolr/conf

4) Create a file named core.properties at $SOLR_INSTALL/server/solr/mysolr

#Derfinition of Core
name=mycore
config=solrconfig.xml
schema=schema.xml
dataDir=data
```

Start your solr server, you can see your core in solr admin UI.
After this you are good to use solrconfig.xml under `$SOLR_INSTALL/server/solr/mysolr/conf`